# Temporary switch app key in Laravel and use it for en/decryption of strings

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, crypt

I want to use Laravel's 8 Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt but with a different key. Is there a package available for this or can it be done? i tried a encrypted message, and then change the key, and the old key:

```
config(['app.key' => 'base64:aesKxxmSf0Vtqyuf2s1QK/7zuhu3dB+w+....']);
```

before

```
Crypt::decryptString("eyJpdiI6IitxMVhrU2RBV0VLbSt3UjRzN0xabkE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiaDBtWUtiUzc0QVRQdXoyM2ZCeVAyZz09IiwibWFjIjoiYTQwYzdkNzgwODAzNGVlYjM2NDZiM2Y4M2NhYTA2ZjE2NjFhZjFiNTYwN2U1NzVhNWVlZDM...");
```

but that did not trigger a temporary key change as i got this error:

```
Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\DecryptException
The MAC is invalid.
```

When i changed it back to the old key, all works fine.

So i guess the key is already in the memory to be used for the **Crypt::decryptString**.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Laravel registers the encrypter as a singleton during bootstrapping within the `Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider`, thus changing the app key does not do anything once the Service Provider ran.

Your best option might be to create an own instance of the Encrypter like this:

```php
$encrypter = new Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter(base64_decode($appKey), config('app.cipher'))
```

where `$appKey` is the key you wish to use for decoding, **without** the `base64:` prefix.

You can then just call

```php
$encrypter->decryptString("eyJpdiI6IitxMVhrU2RBV0VLbSt3UjRzN0xabkE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiaDBtWUtiUzc0QVRQdXoyM2ZCeVAyZz09IiwibWFjIjoiYTQwYzdkNzgwODAzNGVlYjM2NDZiM2Y4M2NhYTA2ZjE2NjFhZjFiNTYwN2U1NzVhNWVlZDM...");
```

to decrypt your payload.